# Proof: A (real) polynomial of degree d has at most d (real) roots

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, proof-explanation

A (real) polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ (real) roots

The catch is the only things I can cite are

1) The Division Algorithm for Polynomials

2) Prop 6.19: Let p(x) be a real polynomial. The number z is a root of p(x) iff there exists polynomial q(x) such that p(x)=(x-z)q(x).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: If you already know that $z$ is a root iff $x-z$ divides $p$ then I really don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Don't forget that $\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$.

Comment: what is the degree of the polynomial $q(x)$? The next step is apply proposition to $q(x)$ and so forth until you reach polynomial of zero degree

Comment: @Vasya A.k.a., "induction."

Comment: @ClementC.: Yes, of course!